# How to call the function outside the grid panel?Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4

"I'm trying to call the function from outside grid panel in ExtJS, but I 
   am not sure why I am not able to call, is there any scope issue, Please 
   help me to figure out this problem

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
title: 'A Panel',
fullscreen: true,

tools: [{
   type: 'help',
   handler: function() {
       var self=this;
       var receiveData = self.getData();
       alert(receiveData);
   }
   }, {
   itemId: 'refresh',
   type: 'refresh',
   hidden: true,
   handler: function () {
       // do refresh
   }
  }, {
   type: 'search',
   handler: function (panel) {
       // do search
       panel.down('#refresh').show();
   },
   scope:this
   }]
   });
  //previous
  function getData(){
  var item="Test";
  return item;
  }

 //updated
  getData:function (){
  var item="Test";
  return item;
  }
```

I need to alert test message from the getData()

Comment: The way you declared geData() makes it a global function, just remove the "self" and it should work.

Comment: @Fabio Barros  Thanks it works

Comment: @FabioBarros what if i use function expression instead say getData:function()